# Is there a way in numpy/matplotlib etc to get the function of a graph?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def model(y,t):
    dydt= 0.6*(2.11-y)-1.17*(4.767-4.767*np.exp(-1.4*y))
    return dydt

y0=0

t = np.linspace(0,10)

y = odeint(model,y0,t)

plt.plot(t,y)
plt.xlabel("t")
plt.ylabel("S")
plt.show()
```

This code produces a graph, the need the equation/function of it. Is there any way of getting it ??

I have searched many times, but theres no answers to this kind of questions.

Comment: `plt.plot` works with arrays, not functions.  And the output of `odeint` is an array as well.

Comment: In programming terms, your `model` is a `function`.That's not a mathematical 'equatuon'.  There is a symbolic package  called `sympy` that has `symbols`, `functions` and `expressions`.

Comment: you can fit a curve (square root e.g) to it and find optimal parameters, which you can use for getting your mathematical function. Check here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html